# How do Bane bonuses from multiple sources stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

If I have a +1 [dragons-bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bane) [Body Wrap of Mighty Strikes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/body-wrap-of-mighty-strikes) and a +1 dragons-bane [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists), what happens? Do my unarmed strikes have an enhancement bonus vs dragons of +4 or +6 (or something else)? Do I deal an extra 2d6 or 4d6 points of damage against dragons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rules on bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus) say:

> Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater bonus granted applies.

and

> Bonuses without a type always stack, **unless they are from the same source**.

And Bane property have this part:

> A bane weapon excels against certain foes. Against a designated foe, the weapon's enhancement bonus is +2 better than its actual bonus. It also deals an extra 2d6 points of damage against such foes.

It looks pretty clear that +2 to hit, as enhancement bonus, would not stack and in that regard, you are able to use only +2 from Bane, not +4. Also, both increase actual bonus, so even if we would say both works, it's still only 2 higher than it was.

It is a bit more complicated with 2d6 points of bonus damage. This bonus is untyped, so should stack. But both came from the same source - Bane property. One might argue that they came from separate items, so source is not the same. I can't agree, such interpretation would mean that "same source" rule is never applicable, and if that was the intent, it simply shouldn't be there at all.

**tl;dr**: Bane can't be applied many times to the same attack.

Comment: The biggest reason I +1 this is that the bodywrap adds qualities to your unarmed attack, the same way the amulet does.  Basically, a weapon (including unarmed attack) can't be enchanted with two copies of dragon bane at the same time, even if some of the enchantments are coming from a different item.  *However*, you can put different enchants on the bodywrap than on the amulet and have them all for a few attacks per round.  A flaming frost shock amulet with a +1 dragon bane corrosive bodywrap is...  intimidating.